# What does the DTMobileIS mean for?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, xcode-instruments

When I used `Instruments` tool to monitor my memory usage, I found a process named `DTMobileIS` use about 40% of real memory, and then there were not enough memory for my app so it crashed. I am curious about this `DTMobileIS` means for. Does anyone know about it?

**Edit:** 
It seems like `DT` is the prefix of `Debug Tool`. And according to [this link](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/9873-8mb-too-much-memory-didreceivememorywarning.html), `IS` sounds like the abbreviation of `Instruments`.

Comment: I searched and it looks like that's the instrumentation process that sends data for Instruments from the iPhone to your computer.

Comment: @icktoofay: I think so too. It sometimes eats too many memories and makes my app ternimate under instruments.

Comment: I doubt you are running out of memory because of DTMobileIS. Look for leaks in your classes.

Comment: “DT” stands for “Developer Tools”, Apple's name for the entire collection of Xcode-related apps, app dev libraries, dev-related system processes (such as `DTMobileIS`), et. al.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

DTMobileIS- which I believe is the Mobile Instruments Data Server that provides info to instruments window on your Mac. I'm on the hairy edge of performance so I definitely notice the extra 7-10% CPU boost when not using instruments! It eats about 1.5-2.0MB of your precious memory while running the Activity Monitor.

debugserver- which handles console outputs, breakpoints, etc. not a big CPU user, but it is currently consuming 1.24MB in the window I'm watching right now.

So outside of a debugging/instruments environment you should have at least 3MB more memory available, and up to 10% more CPU time available according to my current readings

Comment: Forgot to add in the :D.... http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/9414-how-much-memory-does-instruments-itself-use.html